# Best way to keep authenticated user profile in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

I am using Angular2 & Auth0 to Authenticate a user. 
Currently, according to their "best-practice" , the user profile is saved to localStorage , and once you need to pull information, take it from there. 
This sounds like a bad practice to me, is there a better way to keep logged in profile for local query (name, photo etc.)? maybe using an Angular2 service?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if you want to keep the user profile for later use (if the user close the window and reopen it later) without having to make request to a server. Then you need to store it somewhere.

And storage facilities in the browser are quite limited: [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) for database storage with query capabilities, indexes, etc, [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for simple key=>value storage,or even [`cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) for a limited amount of data as plain-text.

but if you don't need the data for a later use, you can keep it in memory (in a service, for example).

You can also combine both in-memory and offline-storage in a service.

Comment: I am logging the user in using FB, and displaying profile image and name in the top bar. In such case, if the user closes the window and open again on my website, I would like to have the image and name - how would you recommend doing that?

Comment: if you only keep these informations, you could keep it in localStorage (do not keep sensitive informations though). If you need more "intensive" data-processing like making queries over several stored documents, then go for IndexedDB.

Comment: for how long this information could last (is it better to use cookie if I want it to be like on FB , so as long the user hasn't disconnected he will be logged in)?

Comment: Can you provide an example/link explaining how to do this in a service?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both ways.
Storing it in `localstorage` to get that infos without request them anytime and wrapping a `Service` around it to not address the storage from everywhere.